Does Devi Durga also wear the Skull-garland?
I recently decided to make a painting of Goddess Durga based on some sculpture, and I came across this one on Google.
Here she is dancing wearing a garland of skulls: usually a trait of Kali. But she has 10 hands (and Kali has 4) which is wierd. As I understand the story, it is about the metamorphosis of Adishakti (active energy of the universe) through different forms (the 9 forms Navadurga), and with this logic the said sculpture either:

Represents a hybrid state of the Adishakti between Durga and Kali, or
the Sculptor was out of his mind!!

So, does Durga wear the Skull garland in any case? Is my intuition correct? Or the sculptor was really a confused person?


Is this piece old or recent ?

@অনু, I don't know. But the picture is certainly recently taken.

Among the forms of Durga, only the 18 armed Ugrachanda as described in the Kalikapurana wears mundamala. But in this case, the sculptor or the patron caused this deviation for visual effects (probably). This is extremely commonplace nowadays. However, Matsyapurana condemns unsanctioned modifications to icons of divinities.
